# Error using scicpy.integrate.odeint and sympy symbols

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, odeint

I'm trying to solve the following system: d²i/dt² + R'(i)/L di/dt + 1/LC i(t) = 1/L dE/dt as a set of coupled first order differential equations:

- di/dt = k
- dk/dt = 1/L dE/dt - R'(i)/L k - 1/LC i(t)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#Define model: x = [i , k] 

def RLC(x , t):
    
    i = sp.Symbol('i')
    t = sp.Symbol('t')

    #Data: 
    E = sp.ln(t + 1)
    dE_dt = E.diff(t)
    
    R1 = 1000   #1 kOhm
    R2 = 100    #100 Ohm  
    R = R1 * i + R2 * i**3
    dR_di = R.diff(i)
    
    i = x[0]
    k = x[1]
    L = 10e-3   #10 mHy
    C = 1.56e-6 #1.56 uF
    
    #Model
    di_dt = k
    dk_dt = 1/L * dE_dt - dR_di/L * k - 1/(L*C) * i
    dx_dt = np.array([di_dt , dk_dt])
    
    return dx_dt

#init cond:
x0 = np.array([0 , 0])

#time points:
time = np.linspace(0, 30, 1000)

#solve ODE:
x = odeint(RLC, x0, time)

i = x[: , 0]
```

However, I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'`

So, I don't know if `sympy` and `odeint` don't work well together. Or maybe is it a problem because I defined `t` as `sp.Symbol`?

Comment: What are you hoping to get from the `odeint` call?  `odeint` does numeric integration.  The ability to use `sympy` objects in `numpy/scipy` code is very limited.  Don't mix them until you are an expert in both.

Comment: @hpaulj I was hoping to solve for `i` using `odeint`. My idea is to just plot and visualize the response of the system.

Comment: When you ask about an show the **whole** error.  I don't know where the error occurs.

Comment: Don't mix variable name usage.  If `i,t` are symbols, don't use them as numeric variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you differentiate a function, you get a function back. So you need to evaluate it at a point in order to get a number. To evaluate a sympy expression, you could use `.subs()` but I prefer `.replace()` which feels more powerful (at least for me).

You must try and make every single variable have its own name in order to avoid confusion. For example, you replace the float input `t` with a sympy `Symbol` from the very beginning, thus losing the value of `t`. The variables `x` and `i` are also repeated in the outer scope which is not good practice if they mean different things.

The following should avoid confusion and hopefully produce something that you were expecting:

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint


# Define model: x = [i , k]

def RLC(x, t):
    # define constants first
    i = x[0]
    k = x[1]
    L = 10e-3  # 10 mHy
    C = 1.56e-6  # 1.56 uF
    R1 = 1000  # 1 kOhm
    R2 = 100  # 100 Ohm

    # define symbols (used to find derivatives)
    i_symbol = sp.Symbol('i')
    t_symbol = sp.Symbol('t')

    # Data (differentiate and evaluate)
    E = sp.ln(t_symbol + 1)
    dE_dt = E.diff(t_symbol).replace(t_symbol, t)

    R = R1 * i_symbol + R2 * i_symbol ** 3
    dR_di = R.diff(i_symbol).replace(i_symbol, i)
    
    # nothing should contain symbols from here onwards
    # variables can however contain sympy expressions

    # Model (convert sympy expressions to floats)
    di_dt = float(k)
    dk_dt = float(1 / L * dE_dt - dR_di / L * k - 1 / (L * C) * i)
    dx_dt = np.array([di_dt, dk_dt])

    return dx_dt


# init cond:
x0 = np.array([0, 0])

# time points:
time = np.linspace(0, 30, 1000)

# solve ODE:
solution = odeint(RLC, x0, time)

result = solution[:, 0]
print(result)
```

Just something to note: the value `i = x[0]` seemed to sit very close to 0 throughout each iteration. This means `dR_di` stayed basically at `1000` the whole time. I'm not familiar with `odeint` or your specific ODE, but hopefully this phenomenon is expected and isn't a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not sure how to replace the symbols with the variables, so thanks for that. The response is all right, it is what is expected.